# How to post two values in an option field into the one column in table

Tags: php, mysql

```
job_category{
category_id PRIMARY KEY,
category_name
}

job{
job_id PRIMARY KEY,
role
category_id FOREIGN KEY
}

exam{
exam_id AUTO INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
exam_name,
job_cat
}
```

//job_cat is con-cat value as job_id-category_id

This is my select option

```
<select name="job_cat" id="select_item" required="true">
<option value="">Select the Job Role</option>
<?php 

$sql1="SELECT Cat.category_id category_id, Cat.category_name category_name, Job.job_id job_id, Job.role role FROM job Job LEFT JOIN job_category Cat ON Job.category_id=cat.category_id";

$result1= mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql1);
while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){?>
<option value="<?php echo $row1["job_id"] . "-" . $row1["catergory_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row1["role"] . " - " . $row1["catergory_name"] ;?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

//insert values

```
$exam_name=$_POST['exam_name'];
$job_cat=$_POST['job_cat'];

$sql2= "INSERT INTO exam_paper (exam_name,job_cat) VALUES ('$exam_name','$job_cat')";
```

this is not work properly.
Ths insert only the job_id into the 'job_cat' column. category_id not added.
 how can I fix it

Comment: why you need to store both. Based on your table structure only `job_id` is needed to insert into `job_cat` column. because job have it's corresponding `category_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will insert your data just put your column name instead of column_name

```
$job_cat=$_POST['job_cat'];
$ins=mysqli_query("insert into column_name values ('".$job_cat."')");
if($ins)
{echo "data inserted";}
else
{echo "data not inserted";}
```

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

in your table replace `job category` with `job_category`
and your  insert query with

```
INSERT INTO exam_paper (`exam_name`,`job_cat`) VALUES ('".$exam_name."','".$job_cat."')
```

Comment: I want to add 'job_id'- 'category_id' into job_cat column, then how to add a varible to 'list($job_id,$catergory_id)'                                                     list($job_id,$catergory_id) = explode("-", $_POST['job_cat'], 2);

Comment: can you please explain deeply so i can properly fix this, what do you exactly want to do?

Comment: there is a input field to add exam name, and also select option to select role of job.The role preview with the category name as example: 'Manager - IT' in here Manager is role, IT is category_name.      Then how assign variables and write query to insert values using php

Comment: so you want to marge role and category and display them in to your dropdown and insert selected data into database?\

Comment: I merge and add role - category to select option field... Now I want to insert selected data into exam_paper table in the database. How can I insert merge data

Comment: did you use submit button like <input type = "submit">?

Comment: yes.. I use $job_cat=$_POST['job_cat']; then role_id is only added to the job_cat column..not added category_id.

Comment: 'list($job_id,$catergory_id)' list($job_id,$catergory_id) = explode("-", $_POST['job_cat'], 2); is this want to write to insert data?

Comment: yes.. Then how I assign variable $job_cat to this part  
'list($job_id,$catergory_id)' list($job_id,$catergory_id)

Comment: for that you have to concatenate both variables like $job_cat= $job_id.$catergory_id